# how to do loop query for all alphabet a to z ( a-z )?

Tags: postgresql

this is the query i exceute :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION alphabetloop () 
   RETURNS RECORD AS $$ 
DECLARE
   counter INTEGER := 64 ; 
   hsl text :=  'select 1';
   hasil RECORD;
   hasile RECORD;
   i INTEGER := 0 ; 
   j INTEGER := 1 ;
BEGIN

LOOP 
EXIT WHEN counter = 90 ; 
counter := counter + 1 ; 
SELECT j, i + j INTO i, j ;
select concat(hsl,concat(' union all select count(*) FROM public.table_name where field_name like ''',(concat(chr(counter),'%''')))) into hsl;
END LOOP ; 
for hasil in EXECUTE hsl
        loop                                        
select hasil into hasile;
RAISE NOTICE '% : %', chr(counter),hasil;
END LOOP ; 

RETURN hasile;
END ; 
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

select alphabetloop();
```

data output:
("(13911)")

message output:

NOTICE:  Z : (1)

NOTICE:  Z : (3411)

NOTICE:  Z : (446)

...

NOTICE:  Z : (13)

Successfully run. Total query runtime: 52 secs 47 msec.
1 rows affected.

is there a way to return data output to be like:

A | (1)

B | (3411)

C | (446)

D | (166)

...

Z | (13)

Answer (score 3):

**chr(int)** [function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-string.html) Character with the given code. For UTF8 the argument is treated as a Unicode code point. For other multibyte encodings the argument must designate an ASCII character. The NULL (0) character is not allowed because text data types cannot store such bytes.

```
SELECT chr(n)
FROM GENERATE_SERIES(97, 97+25) AS t(n);
```

Comment: thanks, this really help me. i can simplify my query to as like: 

SELECT chr(n), count(*)/1000 as tot_in_k, count(*) FROM GENERATE_SERIES(65, 65+25) AS t(n),public.t_name where public.t_name.f_name like concat(chr(n),'%') group by t.n;

Answer (score 0):

Do some modification to your second loop:

```
   counter := 64 ; 
   for hasil in EXECUTE hsl
            loop     
    counter := counter + 1 ;                                    
    select hasil into hasile;
    select concat(chr(counter), '|', hasil);
    END LOOP ;
```